# Upgrading TYPO3 to v8 LTS via the BE?

Tags: typo3

I want to update my TYPO3 8.7.8 to the v8 LTS, but i can't seem to find any way to do this via the Backend. Do i need to manually install the new version as a fresh installation?

Comment: If you look for something called 8 LTS you can't find them. Now TYPO3 8.7.9 is equal to TYPO3 v8 LTS. You can update to them via install tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add `TYPO3` Source manually if you have create symlinks in your typo3 installation and already running with TYPO3 Version `8.7.x`.

If your TYPO3 Version running in `6.2.x` Then First you need to upgrade TYPO3 Version `7.6` and after TYPO3 `8.7.` You can't upgrading Directly version `8.7` if your systems is running in `6.2.x.`

Just you need to follow below steps.

1. Login TYPO3 BE and Go To Install Tool.
2. In **Important actions** you see the **Check for core updates** button. click on this, Here you can find latest TYPO3 version.
3. After download latest TYPO3 Version. Click on **Compare current database with specification** and update typo3 core Database.
4. After compare DB Go to **Upgrade Wizard** and perform all required steps.

**Note**: When performs all above steps first you need to take a backup of your database. So, in case of any problems then you can restore old DB.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the upgrade guide in the docs

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/Upgrade/Index.html